# react-static-boilerplate can't run index.html without node (but it works on aws s3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, react-boilerplate

I'm trying to run the react-staic-boilerplate on my local machine without using node, by opening the index.html file under public folder (after running yarn build/npm run build).

When I double click the index.html to serve on chrome, inspector tells me that the pathing to /dist/main.xxxx.js is wrong - which is fine, I go and manually fix the pathing error inside index.html. But then index.html instantly redirects me to the 404 page, telling me that Pages xx cannot be found. I tried debugging in vain but there's 30k lines of code after webpack compiled the whole thing.

Why is this the case? Shouldn't the buillt static files work on chrome without relying on serverside technology(node)?

I mean, index.html works fine when I upload the entire public folder onto aws s3. The mainpage, links, everything works after I point the entry point on s3 as index.html.

So if I'm understanding this correctly, aws s3 simply serves files, and if it works on s3, it should work on local machine (without node, since react-static-boilerplate can be pure clientside without relying on server).

Will anyone help me out? The backend teamlead refuses to approve any sort of react boilerplate unless we can prove to him that it runs on chrome clientside 100% without using node/serverside assistance.

Comment: In case of `s3`, amazon serves your static files like static `http` server that's why you are able to run it perfectly. Incase of local machine, you are not serving these files through any web server, that's why it is not working. You should use `node` or `apache` for serving these static files.

Comment: You need a minimal web server to serve the static files. If you have python installed, try: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the directory where index.html is located.

Comment: @MukeshSharma Oh cool that's good to know, but why does a simple react index.html page work by itself? By simple, I mean a line of html that says Hello World using jsx and babel cdn translator. I've tried doing that locally with just index.html and that works. Do you only begin needing a HTTP server after including things like npm modules/webpack? Perhaps my question is, at what point do you start needing to use a simple http server?

Comment: @Giladd Thanks for the reply! Do you know at what point would I require to use http server? Because a very basic and simple react page can run with just index.html, so I'm curious at what stage would I need to use a http server

Comment: When you open an html file from the file system, it is similar to opening a docx file using word - the file is not served over http, it is read from disk. If the html file requests more resources (like js files), it will expect to communicate with a server, usually over http. If the resources are remote (like a CDN), there is already a server waiting to serve them. If they are local - by default there is no server to receive the request and serve it, so you need to run one.

Comment: I'm quite a bit late to this - but wanted to point out a problem in a few of the comments. You do not need an http server for an html file to open a local .js file, it'll work just fine without one. For anyone that doesn't believe so - test it with create-react-app. Build it, remove the leading slash in the two local URLs in index.html, and then open the page. It works just fine.

If an example can be provided we could probably figure it out. But using something like Express to create custom routes will causing problems when trying to test it locally.